# postgresql group by a column of a joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to make a sql request that is grouped by a column of a joined table

here are the tables

```
STUDENT
--------
student_id
name

COURSE
------
course_id
title

STUDENTS_COURSES
----------------
student_id
course_id
date
```

I want to aggregate the STUDENT.student_id grouped by STUDENTS_COURSES.date and at the same time take the maximum date
(The reason I want to aggregate STUDENT.student_id and not directly STUDENTS_COURSES.student_id is that afterwards I want to put another grouped by column of STUDENT )

I carried out the following request that give bad result

```
select array_agg( std.id), std_co.date 
from STUDENT std 
join STUDENTS_COURSES std_co on std.student_id = std_co.student_id 
and std_co.date = (select max(std_co_2.date) from STUDENTS_COURSES std_co_2 where std_co_2.student_id = std_co.student_id) 
group by std_co.date ;
```

### UPDATE

```
STUDENT
student_id    name
   1         dubois
   2         dupont
   3         martin

STUDENTS_COURSES
----------------
student_id    course_id      date
    1            1         23/01/2021
    2            3         23/01/2021
    3            5         23/01/2021
    1            2         21/01/2021
    2            8         21/01/2021
    3            9         21/01/2021
```

I want the the following result of select

```
(1,2,3)    23/01/2021
   ^           ^
   ¦           ¦
 student_id    date
```

it must be a group clause, as I will also group by another columns and the first result must be extracted from STUDENT.student_id

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.see my update and I add it must be a group by clause as I will add later other group by clause from students table column. furthermore for the first output (list of STUDENT.student_id) I must use the table STUDENTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry this solution  works

```
select array_agg( std.id), mxdate.created_at 
from 
STUDENT std 
join (select std_co .student_id, max(std_co .date) as created_at 
from STUDENTS_COURSES std_co group by std_co .student_id) mxdate 
on mxdate.student_id = std.student_id 
group by mxdate.created_at;
```

the discussion is closed. thank you for your help